# Cypress wait for xhr logging

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cypress

i want to wait for the logging of this url: **/hdlasrlogging**

This logs every event that occurs in the background and saves the Msg of the event in the requestbody. So every event has a different Msg.

For example like this:

[image]

I try to accomplish this with that function:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('waitAtLoggingMsg', (logMsg)=>{

    return(
        cy.wait('@logging').then(data=>{
            let msg = data.requestBody.msg;
            expect(msg).to.include(logMsg);
        })
    );

});
```

In this part of the test

```
            cy.url().should('include', text.links.segmentmeasurements);

            cy.waitAtLoggingMsg('FETCH_SEGMEAS_LIST_OVERVIEW_SUCCESS');
            cy.get('[data-testid = "TableBody"]').should('not.be.empty');
```

---

It should  wait until all the entries from the db are loaded.
Currently it just waits for the first logging but the one i'm looking for is behind.

[image]

---

Do you got any suggestions?

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: You can see it in the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing here is that `getByTestId` does not retry if the upcoming assertion fails. It only tries once, and the first time the data has not been processed yet.

The commands from `cypress-testing-library` are known to have this shortcoming.

Default cypress commands do retry so if you were to select with `.get()` you will not have this issue.

If you want to stick with `cypress-testing-library` there is a workaround using `.should(fn)`, but in your case, this is tricky because `.waitAtLoggingMsg()` does not retry either and is recursive to boot. This puts you in a very awkward spot to use the workaround.

The best way I can see without context is to ditch `.waitAtLoggingMsg()` in favor of something like:

```
cy.url()
    .should('include', text.links.segmentmeasurements)
    .should(() => {
        cy.getByTestId('TableBody')
            .should('not.be.empty');
    });
```

This will retry the `getByTestId()` command in a crude way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This would work, but my Problem is that i want to wait for the logging. I've just edited my code and post.

Comment: In that case consider using 3 `.should()` commands. In the second `.should()` call `.waitAtLoggingMsg()` and remove the recursion from that command as `.should()` will handle retrying for you.